# why 'pt_core_news_sm' of spacy's doesn't exist

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have installed spacy's Portuguese package:

> python -m spacy download pt_core_news_sm

And also did this:

> python -m spacy download pt

However, for this line:

```
token_transform[TGT_LANGUAGE] = get_tokenizer('spacy', language='pt_core_news_sm')
```

I get this error message:

> OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'pt_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Any ideas?